# regex match href without passing closing tag

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex to parse document links (pdf, ppt, xls, doc) in a html page. I have the regex as non-greedy but the issue I am seeing is the following:

- A href to a HTML page appears before the href to the document on the same line.

In this case the regex matches from the start of the href for the HTML page to the end of the document file extension in the following href on the same line.

Here's the regex I am using:

```
/href="\/cms\/(.*?\.(pdf|ppt|xls|doc))(\?.*?)?"/i
```

Here's some sample HTML to parse:

```
<a href="/cms/medical/plans_overview.html">Medical</a></div><a href="/cms/docs/mydoc.pdf">
```

Currently this matches from the first href to the last pdf. Seems like I need to be able specify that I want the match as long as it doesn't pass a closing ">" in the expression but have not been able to figure this out.

Would appreciate any help ...

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you choose regex to perform this task?

Comment: it seemed like the best approach to dynamically parsing a large set of pages without having to write and maintain a lot of string parsing logic. of course the problem with regexs is that if you don't have a lot experience with them you can spend hours looking at how to get a regex to work

Comment: You might want to look into using XPath queries instead of RegEx; technically html markup isn't a _regular_ languages so if you use _regular_ expressions to process html or xml, it won't always work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your attribute value is wrapped into double quotes, you can exclude them being matched:

```
/href="\/cms\/([^"]*?\.(pdf|ppt|xls|doc))(\?[^"]*?)?"/i
```

You can narrow the valid characters even more by using `[^<"]`.

Comment: that's awesome and seems blindingly obvious once you see it. thanks.